# Titanium Alloy scrolling stops immediately on Android

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I'm using Titanium 3.4 and Ally 1.5.1 for a crossplatform app (iOS and Android).
I have a problem with my TableViews and ScrollViews. When the content is larger than the screen, the Views are correctly scrollable but on iOS when I use a swipe gesture the view keeps scrolling for a bit until it comes to a stop. On Android however, as soon as I pull my finger from the screen it stops scrolling.

I've installed the "Todo list" sample app and it doesn't have this behaviour on Android, after a swipe the list keeps scrolling.

How can I activate this continuous scrolling feature on Android? (or how did I accidentaly deactivate it)

A sample view:

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="experiencesList">
        <View id="contentWrapper">
            <TableView class="cTable" id="experienceTable" onClick="experienceListOnClick"/>
        </View>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

A sample tss:

```
"#experiencesList":{
    width: Ti.UI.Fill,
    height: Ti.UI.Fill,
    layout: "absolute"
},
"#contentWrapper":{
    top: "0dp",
    height: Alloy.Globals.appConfig.contentHeight,
    backgroundColor: "white"
},
"TableView":{
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    top: 0,
    separatorInsets: {
        left: 0,
        right: 0
    },
    scrollable: true,
    separatorColor: "black"
},
"TableView[platform=ios]":{
    scrollIndicatorStyle: Titanium.UI.iPhone.ScrollIndicatorStyle.BLACK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a 'swipe' event defined somewhere? I've experienced this on Android when I have a horizontal swipe on a Listview that also has vertical scrolling.

The issue below from Titanium resolved with a "Won't fix" is stating that this is standard Android behavior:

> The swipe event is eating the scroll event. This is expected behavior
>   with the current Android architecture. Swipe event is not recommended
>   to use along with a scrollable widget.

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-16344

Comment: Yes, I read that somewhere as well so I checked. No swipe events anywhere :)